# AD FS - Having Federated Web SSO, the Account partner fails to login to SharePoint, whereas Resource partner is OK

Tags: sharepoint, adfs

When implementing [Federated Web SSO](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/deployment/checklist--implementing-a-federated-web-sso-design) design between to access SharePoint in resource partner organization and when seemingly doing everything correctly as within step-by-step tutorial [Windows Server 2012 R2 AD FS – Federated Web SSO](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/platformspfe/2014/08/28/part-1-windows-server-2012-r2-ad-fs-federated-web-sso/), something wasn't quite right.

- **The account organization users cannot log** on because browser is jumping between resource partner and account partner ADFS until it generates following Event ID 364 on account partner ADFS: `Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.InvalidRequestException: MSIS7042: The same client browser session has made '6' requests in the last '3' seconds. Contact your administrator for details.`
- The resource partner organization users have no issues logging in
- It is not related to saml token timestamp. I checked the lifetime was being set correctly. No timezone issues or other configuration issues with that.
- I am seeing Primary SID being issued, but was wondering why EMail token doesn't get issued which is set as identifier claim within SharePoint
- On Account partner ADFS server, I am passing Email claim onto Resource Partner Relying Party. On resource Partner ADFS server, within Claim Provider, I am Passing (accepting) email claim. On the relying party I am mapping ldap attribute email to outgoing email claim (oops, this last sentence is the culprit actually, but was not obvious for me)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[A comment on an answer](https://serverfault.com/a/698070/8965) to another question leads to a solution stating that:

> I did not have pass through claim rules for sharepoint on the RP ADFS
>   server.

Turns out for SharePoint Relying Party I had a rule "Send LDAP Attributes as Claims" that mapped incoming email claim to outgoing email claim. Turns out **I needed a "Pass Through or Filter an Incoming Caim" to just pass it**.

Bingo. The "Send LDAP attributes..." rule implies that one must query Active Directory Attribute Store. Well, the resource partner has no info to fetch from his own AD to extract email address. And thus I just need to pass it thru, but not fetch my own AD. The [Create a Rule to Send LDAP Attributes as Claims
 documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/operations/create-a-rule-to-send-ldap-attributes-as-claims) states this:

> Using the Send LDAP Attributes as Claims rule template in Active
>   Directory Federation Services (AD FS), you can create a rule that will
>   **select attributes from a Lightweight Directory Access Protocol (LDAP)**
>   attribute store, such as Active Directory, to send as claims to the
>   relying party. For example, you can use this rule template to create a
>   Send LDAP Attributes as Claims rule that will **extract attribute values**
>   for authenticated users...